# Poetry manage python package CLI

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click, python-poetry

I'm developing a Python package using Poetry with the following structure:

```
/packagename
 /packagename
  /tests
   __init__.py
   test_packagename.py
  __init__.py
  packagename.py
pyproject.toml
```

All the package code is inside packagename.py, which is imported in `__init__.py`.

I want to add a CLI and my goal is to execute the following in the command line:

```
<packagename> <packagefunction>
```

To do so, I used the click package for Python and wrote my `<packagefunction>` inside `packagename.py` as:

```
 @click.command()
 def packagefunction():
```

Currently, I have added entry points into poetry configuration file as:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
<packagefunction> = '<packagename>:<packagefunction>'
```

and run:

```
poetry run <packagefunction>
```

which execute perfectly.

However, I know this is not the correct way to do it and I want the CLI to execute with the commands shown above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To achieve the command line you are after you, you can use a:

#### [`click.Group()`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Group)

```
import click

@click.group()
def main():
    """packagename cli"""
```

And then to use the group, you can use `@main.command()` decorator like:

```
@main.command()
def packagefunction():
    """packagefunction subcommand"""
```

instead of `@click.command()` decorator.

#### [Poetry scripts](https://poetry.eustace.io/docs/pyproject/#scripts)

To have poetry install `packagename` command and call the `main` group in the  `packagename` module:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
# command_name = module_for_handler : function_for_handler
<packagename> = '<packagename>:<main>'
```

instead of:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
<packagefunction> = '<packagename>:<packagefunction>'
```

Comment: Had to add following 
`[tool.poetry]
packages = [
    { include = "packagename", from="." },
]`
Otherwise poetry couldn't run the script with `poetry run packagefunction`